# Flutter secure form string validation

Tags: string, flutter, security, dart

I'm wondering how do you guys secure user input strings in Flutter forms.

I'm using [string_validator](https://pub.dev/packages/string_validator) package to protect the email fields and for regular text fields I was using *isAlphanumeric* checker, but this don't allow the user to use latin alphabet...

It would be nice to hear about your solutions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I use the `inputFormatters` and  a `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter` class with RegExp checking.

```dart
        inputFormatters: [
          WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9 ]"))
        ];
```